# Understanding C++ function Inlining

Tags: c++, visual-c++, inlining

I am using a MS specific keyword to force a global function to be inlined, but I noticed that the function fails to inline itself if it uses an object which does have an explicit trivial destructor.

Quoting from [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/z8y1yy88.aspx)

> Even with `__forceinline`, the compiler cannot inline code in all
>   circumstances. The compiler cannot inline a function if:
>
> - The function or its caller is compiled with `/Ob0` (the default option for debug builds).
> - The function and the caller use different types of exception handling (C++ exception handling in one, structured exception handling
>     in the other).
> - The function has a variable argument list.
> - The function uses inline assembly, unless compiled with `/Og`, `/Ox`, `/O1`, or `/O2`.
> - The function is recursive and not accompanied by `#pragma inline_recursion(on)`. With the pragma, recursive functions are inlined to a default depth of 16 calls. To reduce the inlining depth, use `inline_depth` pragma.
> - The function is virtual and is called virtually. Direct calls to virtual functions can be inlined.
> - The program takes the address of the function and the call is made via the pointer to the function. Direct calls to functions that have had their address taken can be inlined.
> - The function is also marked with the naked `__declspec` modifier.

I am trying the following self contained program to test the behavior

```
#include <iostream>
#define INLINE __forceinline
template <class T>
struct rvalue
{
    T& r_;
    explicit INLINE rvalue(T& r) : r_(r) {}
};

template <class T>
INLINE
T movz(T& t)
{
    return T(rvalue<T>(t));
}
template <class T>
class Spam
{
public:
    INLINE operator rvalue<Spam>()  { return rvalue<Spam>(*this); }
    INLINE Spam() : m_value(0)  {}
    INLINE Spam(rvalue<Spam> p) : m_value(p.r_.m_value) {}
    INLINE Spam& operator= (rvalue<Spam> p) 
    {
        m_value = p.r_.m_value;
        return *this; 
    }
    INLINE explicit Spam(T value) : m_value(value) {    }
    INLINE operator T() { return m_value; };
    template <class U, class E> INLINE  Spam& operator= (Spam<U> u) { return *this; }
    INLINE ~Spam() {}
private:
    Spam(Spam<T>&); // not defined
    Spam& operator= (Spam&); // not defined
private:
    T m_value; 
};
INLINE int foo()
{
    Spam<int> p1(int(5)), p2;
    p2 = movz(p1);
    return p2;
}

int main()
{
    std::cout << foo() << std::endl;
}
```

With the trivial destructor `INLINE ~Spam() {}` in place, we have the following disassembly

```
int main()
{
000000013F4B1010  sub         rsp,28h  
    std::cout << foo() << std::endl;
000000013F4B1014  lea         rdx,[rsp+30h]  
000000013F4B1019  lea         rcx,[rsp+38h]  
000000013F4B101E  mov         dword ptr [rsp+30h],5  
000000013F4B1026  call        movz<Spam<int> > (013F4B1000h)  
000000013F4B102B  mov         rcx,qword ptr [__imp_std::cout (013F4B2050h)]  
000000013F4B1032  mov         edx,dword ptr [rax]  
000000013F4B1034  call        qword ptr [__imp_std::basic_ostream<char,std::char_traits<char> >::operator<< (013F4B2040h)]  
000000013F4B103A  mov         rdx,qword ptr [__imp_std::endl (013F4B2048h)]  
000000013F4B1041  mov         rcx,rax  
000000013F4B1044  call        qword ptr [__imp_std::basic_ostream<char,std::char_traits<char> >::operator<< (013F4B2058h)]  
}
```

where as without the destructor `INLINE ~Spam() {}` we have the following disassembly

```
int main()
{
000000013FF01000  sub         rsp,28h  
    std::cout << foo() << std::endl;
000000013FF01004  mov         rcx,qword ptr [__imp_std::cout (013FF02050h)]  
000000013FF0100B  mov         edx,5  
000000013FF01010  call        qword ptr [__imp_std::basic_ostream<char,std::char_traits<char> >::operator<< (013FF02040h)]  
000000013FF01016  mov         rdx,qword ptr [__imp_std::endl (013FF02048h)]  
000000013FF0101D  mov         rcx,rax  
000000013FF01020  call        qword ptr [__imp_std::basic_ostream<char,std::char_traits<char> >::operator<< (013FF02058h)]  
}
000000013FF01026  xor         eax,eax  
}
```

I am failing to understand, why in the presence of the destructor, the compiler fails to inline the function `T movz(T& t)`

- **Note** The behavior is consistent from 2008 to 2013
- **Note** I checked with cygwin-gcc but the compiler does inlines the code. I cannot verify other compilers at this moment, but would update in next 12 hours if required

Comment: Ask people who wrote the compiler, and possibly file a bug report.

Comment: @n.m.: I would, but before that I want to ask the community, if they are aware of this issue, or if I am missing something obvious :-)

Comment: Is there a `#define` missing? `INLINE __forceinline`

Comment: The destructor of `Spam` is not trivial according to the definition of "trivial" in the C++ Standard. In VS2013, you can try `~Spam() = default;`, this will be trivial IFF the dtor of the data member is trivial.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, it's a bug.
I have tested it on Qt over MinGW compiler environment.  It optimizes everything very well.

First, I have changed your code a little bit as below for easier viewing the assembly code:

```
int main()
{
    int i = foo();
    std::cout << i << std::endl;
}
```

And from my Qt's debug disassembly:

```
        45  int main()
        46  {
0x401600                    lea    0x4(%esp),%ecx
0x401604  <+0x0004>         and    $0xfffffff0,%esp
0x401607  <+0x0007>         pushl  -0x4(%ecx)
0x40160a  <+0x000a>         push   %ebp
0x40160b  <+0x000b>         mov    %esp,%ebp
0x40160d  <+0x000d>         push   %ecx
0x40160e  <+0x000e>         sub    $0x54,%esp
0x401611  <+0x0011>         call   0x402160 <__main>
0x401616  <+0x0016>         movl   $0x5,-0x10(%ebp)
        47      int i = foo();
0x401683  <+0x0083>         mov    %eax,-0xc(%ebp)
        48      std::cout << i << std::endl;
0x401686  <+0x0086>         mov    -0xc(%ebp),%eax
0x401689  <+0x0089>         mov    %eax,(%esp)
0x40168c  <+0x008c>         mov    $0x6fcba2c0,%ecx
0x401691  <+0x0091>         call   0x401714 <_ZNSolsEi>
0x401696  <+0x0096>         sub    $0x4,%esp
0x401699  <+0x0099>         movl   $0x40171c,(%esp)
0x4016a0  <+0x00a0>         mov    %eax,%ecx
0x4016a2  <+0x00a2>         call   0x401724 <_ZNSolsEPFRSoS_E>
0x4016a7  <+0x00a7>         sub    $0x4,%esp
        49  }
0x4016aa  <+0x00aa>         mov    $0x0,%eax
0x4016af  <+0x00af>         mov    -0x4(%ebp),%ecx
0x4016b2  <+0x00b2>         leave
0x4016b3  <+0x00b3>         lea    -0x4(%ecx),%esp
0x4016b6  <+0x00b6>         ret
```

You can even see that foo() is optimized.  You can see that variable 'i' is directly assigned to 5 and is printed.